# ¿Como obtener la cantidad de espacio que ocupa un registro en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Resulta que en mi base de datos tengo una tabla madre donde ingreso información de distintas sucursales, de las cuales necesitaría saber **cuanto es el espacio que ocupan todos los registros de la sucursal 1 en el disco duro** y así con las demás sucursales, para poder sacar el estimado de cuanto es el precio en disco que ocupa cada sucursal.

Espero haber dejado un poco clara mi pregunta, y que así puedan ayudarme a solventar este problema, o si saben de una bibliografía en Internet, es de mucha ayuda!

gracias!

Comment: puede que esto te de alguna información útil http://www.uterra.com/base_datos_mysql/codigo_mysql.php?ref=tamano_de_una_base_de_datos_y_sus_tablas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo así:

Supongamos que la base de datos se llama `mi_db` y la tabla `mi_tabla`.

1. Necesitamos saber **el tamaño total que ocupa de la tabla** en cuestión.

   ```
   SELECT (data_length + index_length) AS tamano_tabla
   FROM information_schema.TABLES 
   WHERE table_schema = "mi_db"
       AND table_name = "mi_tabla";
   ```

   Esta consulta nos devolverá el tamaño en `bytes`
2. Además necesitamos saber **la cantidad total de registros en la tabla**.

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(1) as registros_tabla
   FROM mi_db.mi_tabla;
   ```
3. Luego necesitamos saber **la cantidad de registros que pertenecen a una `sucursal`**

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(1) as registros_sucursal
   FROM mi_db.mi_tabla
   WHERE idSucursal = ID;
   ```
4. Finalmente, utilizando [la regla de tres](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_de_tres):

   ```
   registros_tabla     ---->  tamano_tabla
   registros_sucursal  ---->  X (tamano_sucursal)
   ```

   Es decir que:

   ```
   X = registros_sucursal * tamano_tabla / registros_tabla
   ```

   `X` será **el tamaño que ocupan los registros de la sucursal** en `bytes`